# Angular {{$index}} integration with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, angularjs

I'm not sure that what I'm trying to do is possible.I have an ng-repeat that loops through a `JSON` file and creates input tags with an id of `{{$index}}`.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="option in options">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{$index}}">
  <label for="{{$index}}">{{options}}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now I'm using an external jquery script called customInput which locates the input tags and their id and transforms the regular inputs into custom inputs. I'm pretty sure that the problem is that the script does not recognize `{{$index}}` as an integer or string and throws the following error.

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for={{$index}}]

What is the correct way to communicate between the two?

Thanks ahead

Comment: What are you storing in `variable options`, i mean external JS?

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: @Nadir updated the error message

Comment: @Dhaval I don't really understand your question..

Comment: i mean how `options` are initialized in your external js that you are using  in ng-repeat

Comment: @Dhaveal are you referring to the JSON? if so it is constructed like this - {
        "key1" : "2012HyundaiVeloster",
        "key2" : "HyundaiVelosterTurbo"
}

Answer (score 0):

Hi you might just want to integrate your jquery customInput function into the angular controller, such that you can pass in the $index to whatever function you want in your scope. Here's a Plunker [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/juzr4RUlq14I1h57vJoI?).

It's probably neater too.

Comment: thanks for the answer @hqtay, but your example uses ng-click on every input. I need the index to be passed on passively without a users click.

Answer (score 0):

You should integrate the plugin into a directive. The you should use the $element service of the directive to start the jquery plugin